# ClassNotFoundException in Struts2 Example

Tags: java, struts2, classnotfoundexception

I am running a simple Struts 2 example.

When I run the project using eclipse, I got this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

Earlier I used Struts 2.2 lib then Struts 2.0 libs, but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need [struts2-core](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/Downloadstruts2core2011jar.htm) library in your classpath.

Comment: I had jar both in lib folder and classpath. But got the same exception. It also display's just before exception                   SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2.

Comment: explore it and check if they contain the missing class?

Comment: Actually, it was problem of missing jar. I had download struts-apps.lib and copied the jar of sample application into my project. Then project runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes including the jars in project does not work. so you have to add those jar in your server lib folder which could be your tomcat.

when you run your application using tomcat server it do not found the required jar.

so you have to provide those jars directly to the tomcat by **tomcat lib** folder.